# KeyError when creating a pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure why I'm getting this error. The full script is located here: https://gitlab.com/NERSC/roofline-on-nvidia-gpus/-/blob/master/custom-scripts/postprocess.py

I have a csv with the following columns:

```
"ID","Process ID","Process Name","Host Name","Kernel Name","Kernel Time","Context","Stream","Section Name","Metric Name","Metric Unit","Metric Value"
```

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=cnt-1)
dft=df.groupby(['Kernel Name','Metric Name']).sum()
dfmetric=pd.pivot_table(dft, index='Kernel Name', columns='Metric Name', values='Metric Value')
```

```
KeyError: 'Metric Value'
```

Comment: Is Metric Value numeric. Normally `groupby sum` will exclude non-numeric columns from the output. (Said another way are you sure `dft` _does_ have a Metric Value column?)

Comment: Metric Value is indeed numeric. I added print(dft) before the table is created and the column is there.

Comment: Would you include the output from `print(dft.columns)`?

Comment: It looks like for some reason column "Metric Value" is being skipped during sum.
would you also include dtype of column "Metric Value"  df["Metric Value"].dtype

Comment: Index(['ID', 'Process ID', 'Context', 'Stream'], dtype='object')

Comment: @PavanSuvarna df["Metric Value"].dtype returns object

Comment: Right. So Metric Value is _not_ numeric if it is of type object and is therefore skipped by sum. You'll need to make it _numeric_

Answer (score 0):

After read_csv convert column "metric value" to numeric *[pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)*

```
df["Metric Value"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Metric Value"], errors= 'coerce')
```